Strongly Connected Components (Kosaraju's Algo)
Problem-
Given a Directed Graph with V vertices (Numbered from 0 to V-1) and E edges, Find the number of strongly connected components in the graph.
i am solving this on geeksforgeeks. I have two codes. I do not know the difference because they use the same logic and implementation.
First code
void dfs(int node, vector<vector<int>>& adj, stack<int>& st, vector<bool>& vis) {
    vis[node] = 1;
    for (auto &it : adj[node]) {
        if (!vis[it]) dfs(it, adj, st, vis);
    }
    st.push(node);
}

void dfs2(int node, vector<vector<int>>& adj, vector<bool>& vis) {
    vis[node] = 1;
    for (auto &it : adj[node]) {
        if (!vis[it]) dfs2(it, adj, vis);
    }
}

int kosaraju(int V, vector<vector<int>>& adj) {
    vector<bool> vis(V, 0);
    stack<int> st;

    // First DFS to fill the stack with the finishing times
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (!vis[i]) dfs(i, adj, st, vis);
    }

    // Create the transpose of the graph
    vector<vector<int>> adjRev(V);
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        for (auto &it : adj[i]) {
            adjRev[it].push_back(i);
        }
    }

    // Second DFS to count the number of SCCs
    int cnt = 0;
    vis = vector<bool>(V, 0);
    while (!st.empty()) {
        int node = st.top();
        st.pop();
        if (!vis[node]) {
            dfs2(node, adjRev, vis);
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}


this is running properly and passed all test cases.
Second code-
private:
    int dfs(int v, stack<int> &s, vector<int> &vis, vector<vector<int>> g){
        vis[v] = 1;
        for(auto child : g[v]){
            if(vis[child]  == 0){
                dfs(child, s, vis, g);
            }
        }
        s.push(v);
    }
    int DFS(int v, vector<int> &vis, vector<vector<int>> g){
        vis[v] = 1;
        for(auto child : g[v]){
            if(vis[child]  == 0){
                DFS(child, vis, g);
            }
        }
    }
    public:
    //Function to find number of strongly connected components in the graph.
    int kosaraju(int V, vector<vector<int>>& adj)
    {
        stack<int> s;
        vector<int> vis(V, 0);
       for(int i =0; i<V; i++){
           if(vis[i] == 0)  dfs(i, s, vis, adj);
       }
        vector<vector<int>> g(V);
        for(int i =0; i<V; i++){
            vis[i] =0;
            for(auto y : adj[i]){
                g[y].push_back(i);
            }
        }
        int ct =0;
        while(!s.empty()){
            int x = s.top();
            s.pop();
            if(vis[x] == 0){
                DFS(x, vis, g);
                ct++;
            }
        }
        return ct;
    }

This is giving error- Time Limit Exceeded.
I am not able to find the difference between these two codes. Anyone please explain it.

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

They use the same logic and implementation -- A simple diff on both code snippets shows that they are different.  Why did you expect different implementations to work exactly the same?  That occurs if you literally copied and pasted the working code twice, but you didn't do that.  If you are assuming the code works the same just "by sight", programming doesn't work this way.  You need to debug the non-working code and the working code simultaneously to see where the non-working code diverges from the working code.

i am solving this on geeksforgeeks -- Just to add, that site is known for wrong code, bad examples of C++ code.

vector<vector<int>> g -- Yet another reason why using websites like geeks is a waste of time if you want to learn C++.  A C++ programmer who has been taught the basics will know automatically to pass this by reference.  This mistake also happens to programmers who know python, C#, Java or similar languages, and believes that C++ works the same way in terms of parameter passing.

Your implementation of Kosaraju's algorithm is correct, but your two DFS methods in the second code snippet take in the adjacency list by value, which requires copying the entire graph on each call. This is extremely slow; take the parameters by reference instead.
int dfs(int v, stack<int> &s, vector<int> &vis, vector<vector<int>>& g);
int DFS(int v, vector<int> &vis, vector<vector<int>>& g);

Moreover, since you are not modifying the adjacency list, it is more appropriate to take it by const reference.
